# How to drag and drop multiple SpriteKit Nodes with the same parent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have multiple SKSpriteNodes(some rectangles) which are draggable (I followed the tutorial on [Sprite Kit Tutorial: How To Drag and Drop Sprites](http://www.raywenderlich.com/44270/sprite-kit-tutorial-how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites)). When a collision happens between them, I group them (by making the one rectangle a parent and the other a child). No matter how many rectangles I will combine, I manage always to have one parent and multiple rectangles that belong to it. I am doing this cause I want to move cubes belonging in a group together and I observed that if I move the parent, I move all of its children. What I am doing to achieve this is to transform the group at touchBegin and to make the touchedNode a parent and all the other nodes of the group children of this new parent. I believe that the following image may make things a little bit more clear.

[image: A group of rectangles]

The problem I am facing is that I can drag the group even if I touch at the white space (shown with red circle) included between the horizontal and vertical rectangles. As all rectangles shown in the image have the same parent, I guess that there is a bounding box that include them all and this is why the white space in the middle can trigger a drag event.

Does anyone have any idea how I can deal with this issue?

Is it possible to have a bounding box as shown in the following image?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Instead of making one rectangle a parent, you can make both rectangles the child of an SKNode instance. This way, you can make sure that only the rectangles act as the gateway for any drag events.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write custom hit testing to perform this kind of trick.

For every click -> For every box (within certain range of touch) -> For every other box (within certain range of touch) -> Combine the two box frames into one (CGRectUnion(<#CGRect r1#>, <#CGRect r2#>)) and see if your finger is within the rect.

This might give results for a lot of dispersed rectangles, so limit your initial search of boxes to a given range from the touch itself.

Apart from that it's just simple code.